# Checking if a value exists in one template so that I can create a notification in another template

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-5

I have a bootstrap card that holds a list of information and within that information there is a boolean value. If that value is true, I'd like to show some kind of notification on the card. Here is what it looks like [image]

So if in one of those links there is a value that is true, I'd like something notifying the user that everything is all good and if a value is false, let them know something is wrong. Maybe like a thumbs up and thumbs down from font awesome or something(not important right now). Here is my template that holds that information

```
<link href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header text-dark">
        <div class ="card-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead class = "table-light">
                        <tr class="text-center">
                            <th>Location</th>
                            <th>RSU ID</th>
                            <th>Install confirmed</th>
                            <th>Winter mode</th>
                            <th>Date created</th>
                            <th>Created by</th>
                            <th>Date updated</th>
                            <th>Updated by</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="text-center">
                            <td>{{object.location}}</td>
                            <td>{{object.rsu_id}}</td>
                            {% if object.instln_confirmed %}
                            <td><i class="fas fa-check fa-2xl text-primary"></i></td>
                            {% else %}
                            <td><i class="fas fa-x fa-2xl text-danger"></i></td>
                            {% endif %}
                            {% if object.winter_mode %}
                            <td><i class="fas fa-check fa-2xl text-primary"></i></td>
                            {% else %}
                            <td><i class="fas fa-x fa-2xl text-danger"></i></td>
                            {% endif %}
                            <td>{{object.date_created}}</td>
                            <td>{{object.created_by}}</td>
                            <td>{{object.date_updated}}</td>
                            <td>{{object.updated_by}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
      
    </div>
```

And here is the template that shows all the different cards

```
<div class="row gx-2 justify-content-center">
    {% for object in object_list %}
    <div class="col-sm-4 mb-3">
        <div class="card" style="background-color: lightgrey;">
            <div class="card-header text-primary text-center" style="background-color: lightgrey;">
                <h3 class="text-primary"><strong>{{ object.name }}</strong></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="scroll">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body"> 
                        <div class="row">       
                            {% for info in object.prop_infos.all %}
                            <ul id="list">
                                <li>{{ info.date_created }}</li> |
                                <li><a href="{% url 'telemetry_updates:property_info_detail' info.id %}">{{info.detail|truncatechars:15 }}</a></li>
                                <hr>
                            </ul>
                            {% endfor %}                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Models

```
class Info(models.Model):
    detail = models.TextField(max_length=3000)
    instln_confirmed = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    winter_mode = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    rsu_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='Tc_section')
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='Tup_section')
    date_created = models.DateField('Date created', auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateField('Date updated', auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering=['-date_created']
    

class Property(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    prop_infos = models.ManyToManyField(Info, through='PropertyInfo')
    date_created = models.DateField('Date created', auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateField('Date updated', auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def get_section_info(self):
        return self.prop_infos.order_by('-date_created')




class PropertyInfo(models.Model):
    info = models.ForeignKey(Info, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    prop = models.ForeignKey(Property, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Views

```
@login_required
@group_required('Telemetry Reports')
def create_property_name(request):
    property_name_form = PropertyForm(data=request.POST or None, files=request.FILES or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if property_name_form.is_valid():
            object = property_name_form.save(commit=False)
            object.save()
        
        messages.success(request, f"New property successfully created")
        return redirect('/telemetry_updates/view_properties')
    context = {
        "property_name_form":property_name_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'telemetry_updates/create_property_name.html', context)


# property info create function
@login_required
@group_required('Telemetry Reports')
def create_property_info(request):
    info_form = InfoForm(data=request.POST or None, files=request.FILES or None)
    property_info_form = PropertyInfoForm(data=request.POST or None, files=request.FILES or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("Hello world")

        if info_form.is_valid() and property_info_form.is_valid():
            
            info = info_form.save(commit=False) 
            info.created_by = request.user
            info.save()
            
            property_info = property_info_form.save(commit=False)
            property_info.info = info
            property_info.save()

            property = property_info.prop
            property.prop_infos.add(info)
            property.save()
        
        messages.success(request, f"Report successfully added")
        return redirect('/telemetry_updates/view_properties')
        
    context = {
        "form":info_form,
        "form2":property_info_form,        
    }
    return render(request, 'telemetry_updates/create_property_info.html', context)


# view list of all properties and property infos
@login_required
def view_properties(request):
    object_list = Property.objects.all().order_by('-date_created')

    context = {
        'object_list':object_list,
    }

    return render(request, 'telemetry_updates/view_properties.html', context)


# function to show detail of property infos
@login_required
def property_info_detail(request, pk):
    object = Info.objects.get(id=pk)
    context = {
        'object': object,
    }
    return render(request, 'telemetry_updates/property_info_detail.html', context)


# used to update existing property infos
@login_required
@group_required('Telemetry Reports')
def update_property_info(request, pk):
    update = Info.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = InfoForm(data=request.POST or None, files=request.FILES or None, instance=update)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid() and form.has_changed():
            form = form.save(commit=False)
            form.updated_by = request.user
            form.save()

            messages.success(request, f"Property report successfully updated!")
            return redirect('/telemetry_updates/view_properties')
        else:
            messages.success(request, "No changes were made")
            return redirect('/telemetry_updates/view_properties')
    context = {
        'form':form,
    }
    return render(request, 'telemetry_updates/update_property_info.html', context)


# used to delete section infos
@login_required
@group_required('Telemetry Reports')
def delete_property_info(request,pk):
    delete = get_object_or_404(PropertyInfo, id=pk)
    delete.delete()
    messages.success(request, f"Property report successfully deleted")
    return redirect('/telemetry_updates/view_properties')
```

So essentially what I need to do is loop through this list of details and if in any of them there is a true or false value, notify the user on the card.

Comment: What is that field name which is BooleanField?

Comment: There are actually two..instln_confirmed and winter_mode

Comment: Can you also share model and view for clarity?

Comment: Added models and views

Comment: Do you want to check both `instnl_confirmed` and `winter_mode`?

Comment: Yes, that may be better for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249835/discussion-between-sunderam-dubey-and-fitzgerald).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following in the nested loop:

```html
{% for info in object.prop_infos.all %}
    <ul id="list">
        {% if info.winter_mode and info.instln_confirmed %}
            <p>Everything is right</p>
        {% else %}
            <p> something went wrong.</p>
        {% endif %}
        <li>{{ info.date_created }}</li> |
        <li><a href="{% url 'telemetry_updates:property_info_detail' info.id %}">{{info.detail|truncatechars:15 }}</a></li>
        <hr>
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```